# How do I use pushjs in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, npm, node-modules

So I installed their Npm package. Now I need to link it to Meteor I guess. Installation command is on https://pushjs.org/docs/introduction.

```
var Future = Npm.require( 'fibers/future' );
```

Is how I used Futures. What is the equivalent for Push? I tried

```
var Push = Npm.require( '/push.js' );
```

and some variations but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

so turns out the syntax is this:

```
var Push = require('push.js');
```

Feel free to delete this thread if this was too obvious, but it wasn't for me.. :)